# Rails 5 ancestry gem: Update parent_id with ajax return nil

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ancestry

I try to update parent_id in ancestry gem but return nil.Send parent_id with ajax to update action but save nil.Categories system works like, click input to change parent_id then open modal, selected a category, close modal then save category as changed.But when click to update save nil. How can I fix it ?

ajax code

```
  $.ajax
    type: 'GET'
    data: {parent_id: this.id}
```

categories_controller.rb

```
def update
    @category.parent_id = params[:parent_id]
    @category.update_attributes(category_params)
  end
```

_category.haml

```
       %input.radio_category{:id => "#{category.id}", :name => "radio", :type => "radio", :value => "#{category.name}", remote: true, 'data-parent-id': category.id}>
          = category.name
          - if category.has_children?
            = render partial: "category", locals: { collection: category.children }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have u add parent_id in your controller? category_params?
also if u want update like that add `@category.save` after set `@category.parent_id = params[:parent_id]`

Comment: yes, i changed controller `@category.ancestry = params[:parent_id]` then save . already have category params and ancestry included it. But now can't reached to value of input. `%input#category_parent_id{:name => "category[parent_id]", :type => "hidden", :value => "#{params[:parent_id]}"}/ `  . Also I see return `Parameters: {"parent_id"=>"103", "id"=>"104"}` but when update it `"parent_id"=>"" ` returned.

Comment: If you use ancestry/ don't change it like that, you need to change it via parent_id, also add parent_id in you controller.

Comment: I changed via parent_id. but still continue save nil.